# Object paths in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, aspnetboilerplate

I have an asp.net boilerplate project. I am trying to create a form and write it into database. I have a Index.cshtml file and Index.js file. I cant create object of c# class in javascript. It says "MyProject" is undefined.

```
var requestService =  MyCompany.MyProject.Requests.RequestService;
```

is this valid?
What is the syntax of Paths in javascript?
Is it possible that creating an object in cshtml file and passing it to javascript file?

Comment: JavaScript has no concept of "path". It is unclear what you are asking about. The snippet you posted is syntactically valid JavaScript.

Comment: You can't create C# objects in JavaScript. You will have to render the model (C#) in your views. Then you can access the values of the models in JavaScript using the HTML attribute ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in ASP.NET Boilerplate there are services that we use in controllers. This services can be used in JavaScript file such as

```
var _tenantService = abp.services.app.tenant;
```

In view (cshtml) when we click on submit button, form is being sent to app services.

```
_$form.find('button[type="submit"]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (!_$form.valid()) {
        return;
    }

    var tenant = _$form.serializeFormToObject();
    abp.ui.setBusy(_$modal);
    _tenantService.create(tenant).done(function () {
        _$modal.modal('hide');
        location.reload(true); //reload page to see new tenant!
    }).always(function () {
        abp.ui.clearBusy(_$modal);
    });
});
```

And if we want to add new services or add new methods to services, we have to use camel notation in javascript files. Otherwise it says undefined. For example: I created a method named "NewCreate". I had to call it like "newCreate".

But I still don't know how Javascript accesses to "abp.services.app.tenant;"

Answer (score 0):

Alas, this is not how you do it. The js is client side only, and isn't aware that the .net code exists.